# Sending information from one instance to another instance with a specific name in python

Tags: python, class

I have two classes, A and B, B being a subclass of A. First an instance A is initialized and passed a certain name of the user's choice. Then an arbitrary number of instances of B are created, and they are initialized with the name of the superclass A of which they belong to. How would I go about sending information from each instance of B to A assuming there is an instance of A with the name designated in the initialization of B?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,someinfo,A_name):
        self.someinfo=someinfo
        self.A_name=A_name
```

How would I go about sending the attribute 'someinfo', or by that matter any information, from B to the given instance of A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can initialize `B` with an instance of a

```
class B:
  def __init__(self, someinfo, a_instance):
    self.someinfo = someinfo
    self.a_instance = a_instance

  def send_message_to_a(self):
     self.a_instance.a_function(self.someinfo)

a = A()
bs = [B('hi', a) for i in range(random.randint(1, 10))]
for b in bs:
    b.send_message_to_a() # calls the a function passing someinfo
```

Additionally, as you have it setup B doesn't seem to be a subclass of A at all?

Comment: Oh I see, so instead of passing it the name assigned to the instance of A, you are actually passing that instance of A into B (in this case the instance was a). That makes sense, thanks!